# ¿Cómo construir botones con js con createelement que hagan la misma funcion on click de otro boton?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un boton html que quiero imitar usando create element de js

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$DefaultContent$imgIngresar" id="ctl00_DefaultContent_imgIngresar" src="App_Themes/Imagenes/botonAceptar.png" onclick="openLoading();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$DefaultContent$imgIngresar&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;">
```

pero no lo consigo.

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.id="enviar";
button.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
button.innerHTML = "Enviar";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Tu codigo funciona bien.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Quieres imitar el botón al completo?

Comment: Tienes dos funciones, `openLoading()` y `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()`

Comment: si, esas funciones las quiero agregar a ese boton con js . se puede? @Kiko_L

Comment: si , quiero imitar ese boton @Kiko_L

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que estás intentado hacer? `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` es una función Js propia de asp .net pero no sé si es lo que más te conviene, piensa que estás haciendo un postback que igual no necesitas y que puedes solucionar vía AJAX, por ejemplo.

Comment: Automatizando un proceso de inicio, no , quiciera ver un ejemplo hecho con javascript @Kiko_L

Comment: Creo que no puedes poner dos funciones en el `onclick` como veo que intentas hacer... En cambio, puedes asignar una función aquí: `button.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);` cambiando `myFunction` por `openLoading` y luego en la función `openLoading` llamas a la otra función que intentas asignar... En cuanto a los parámetros que pasas en `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` supongo que están en el contexto y que por tanto podrás recuperarlos por sus ids o sus contenedores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar `addEventListener()` usa `getAttribute()` y `setAttribute()`, así:

```
var atributo = document.getElementById('ctl00_DefaultContent_imgIngresar').getAttribute('onclick');
button.setAttribute("onclick", atributo);
```

Así "copias" el atributo del input al botón. Luego lo puedes poner en el body así:

```
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Revisa [este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JCAguilera/snax1hkd/) y con inspeccionar elemento te darás cuenta de que se copió todo lo que estaba dentro de onclick.

Comment: impresionante, copia el contenido de ese boton pero no hace submit.

Uncaught TypeError: $.blockUI is not a function
    at openLoading 
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: se copio, pero por que no llama a la misma funcion?

Comment: Lo probé utilizando un `alert()` dentro de onclick, y funcionó perfecto, quizás ese error tenga que ver con otra parte de tu código.

Comment: si, necesitaba importar algunas cosas para que funcionara.
tambien cambie la parte del button para que me funcionara en el form .
Agradecido (y)